# Writing to the Windows Security Log

Tags: windows, security, powershell, logging

I have a script that I need to write an audit event to the Windows Security log when it has completed showing the user who ran it.

I can write to any log apart from the security log.

How can I do this?

```
New-EventLog -LogName Security -Source "MyApp"
Write-EventLog -LogName Security -source "MyApp" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "Script run by X"
```

When the name is changed from Security to Application or System, it works - but, I keep getting the following when using Security:

> Write-EventLog : The registry key for the log "Security" for source
>   "msevent" could not be opened. At line:1 char:1
>   + Write-EventLog -LogName Security -source "msevent" -EntryType Information -Event ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Write-EventLog], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand

I am the admin and not sure why this happens, even after trying to modify registry security permissions.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

MS Documentation:

> Only the Local Security Authority (Lsass.exe) has write permission for
>   the Security log. No other account can request this privilege. To
>   write an event to the Security log, use the AuthzReportSecurityEvent
>   function.

here is a link to the documentation: [Event Logging Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363658(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also here is a link that covers accessing the Win API from powershell which should help with the implementation in case you absolutely have to use the Security log: [Use PowerShell to Interact with the Windows API: Part 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1.aspx)

I am sorry to not provide a full example but due to time restrictions this will have to do it for now.

Regards

Comment: It's 5 years later but now there is the Vanara project to help make that easier.

Answer (score 1):

Eleveated processes can write to the security event log by using the [AuthzReportSecurityEvent function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/authz/nf-authz-authzreportsecurityevent).

The [Vanara](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara) project provides .NET interop wrappers for this API and is available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vanara.Core/) for .NET developers.  It would probably serve as a good starting point for creating something that was consumable via PowerShell.